How to find the number of plane waves considered for the wavefunctions on Abinit?
I am working on a tutorial of crystalline cubic silicon of an abinit based software where
I have to find the number of plane waves but I don't really know what I should look for in my input or output file.
I have ecut on my input file but I can't see any information on my G-vectors. I also checked my mpw value but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for

The number of plane waves is an input parameter defined by ecut, see the Abinit theory page. In short, ecut is related to the number of Fourier components that represent your electronic wave functions and in practice we need to truncate the infinite Fourier series. Thus, ecut is a system-dependent parameter you need to carefully converge, for example with respect to the total energy of your system.

Thank you very much!

If you think that my answer was sufficient to your question, please consider accepting it. Thanks!
